# Get XML from resources, or site

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, uri

I have some problem with URI into two last code rows: I try get XML from application resources, and from site. Before it, I executed the same operations with the image - everything worked fine. Exception message in a comments.

```
// Get image from site: 
// "pack://siteoforigin:,,,/http://www.designdownloader.com/item/pngs/user_f036/user_f036-20111114102144-00003.png"

// Get image from building resources (Build Action = Resources).
Uri uri_male_default = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/male.png");

// Get image from site: 
// "pack://siteoforigin:,,,/http://www.designdownloader.com/item/pngl/user_f046/user_f046-20111114102341-00003.png"

// Get image from building resources (Build Action = Resources).
Uri uri_female_default = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/myImages/famale.png"); 

// Create images (it's works fine):
img_male_default = new BitmapImage(uri_male_default);
img_female_default = new BitmapImage(uri_female_default);

//The next both cases ain't working:
// NotSupportedException: URI prefix isn't recognized.     
XElement xml_1 = XElement.Load("pack://application:,,,/SettingsX.xml"); // Get XML from building resources (Build Action = Resources).
XElement xml_2 = XElement.Load("pack://siteoforigin:,,,/https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=51b3145b64e05fef&id=51B3145B64E05FEF%21550");
```

The `XElement.Load` get an URI as parameter. Why I can't to do it with XML?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Judging by the error description I highly doubt whether it's possible to pass a WPF pack URI to `XElement.Load` but you can always use the relative path and it will work, sample code below:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("/SettingsX.xml", UriKind.Relative);
            System.Windows.Resources.StreamResourceInfo info = Application.GetResourceStream(uri); 
            XElement settings = XElement.Load(info.Stream);
```

**EDIT:**

To get the xml file from the web:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string url = "Your URL...";
    var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient();
    webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += HttpsCompleted;
    webClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(url));
}

private void HttpsCompleted(object sender, System.Net.DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error == null)
    {
        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(e.Result, LoadOptions.None);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works fine: I have read XML from application resources. But what about reading XML file from a site?

Comment: I have tried such methods:

`WebClient web = new WebClient();   web.DownloadFile("pack://siteoforigin:,,,/https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=51b3145b64e05fef&id=51B3145B64E05FEF%21550", @"c:\temp\temp.xml");
web.DownloadFile("https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=51b3145b64e05fef&id=51B3145B64E05FEF%21550", @"c:\temp\temp2.xml");`

Maybe SkyDrive by Microsoft creates links, which can't be read by such methods (incompatible format)?

Comment: I have got Exception: "The remote server returned an error: (407) Check of authenticity of the intermediary is required.".

Comment: I have tried for such URL (it is my SkyDrive): `string url = "https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=51b3145b64e05fef&id=51B3145B64E05FEF%21550";`.

Comment: I am trying download SettingsX.xml file

Comment: The URL you're passing through doesn't contain the XML file that's why you're getting the error.You need to find what's the full URL path of your XML file and first try access it in a browser then once you've got that working try WebClient again

Comment: SkyDrive create this link, when I try to create a new shared link for my XML file. :((

Comment: Sorry,but unfortunately that's something I cannot help you with